# How to fix text not going in line?

Tags: html, css

Recently I have started development on my website and when I add this header element to a div with the id "Product" the text wraps into a box like shape and not go straight? How do I fix this?

[image]

I need the text to fill the whole top of the box but whatever I do just doesn't work. This only wraps into a box when I add other elements to the div even if the other text is an absolute position.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
}

#BestProfit {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffbc82;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 60px;
}

#BestProfitDescription {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 100px;
}

.ProductList {
    width: 640px;
    height: 780px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}

.Product {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    width: 300px;
    height: 240px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

#NameText {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 600;
    top: -15px;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: Montserrat,system-ui;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffbc82;
}

#ProfitText {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    font-family: Montserrat,system-ui;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="../Images/Other/Stonk.gif" id="Icon">
        <title id="Title">stonks.in | Bazzar Tracker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Request.js"></script>
        <div id="TopBar">
            <img id="Logo" src="../Images/Other/Logo.png">
            <div id="Pages">
                <a id="OverviewLink" href="../HTML/Overview.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Overview.png">Overview
                </a>
                <a id="ProfitLink" href="../HTML/Profit.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Profit.png">Profit
                </a>
                <a id="SmartLink" href="../HTML/Smart.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Smart.png">Smart
                </a>
                <a id="DemandLink" href="../HTML/Demand.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Demand.png">Demand
                </a>
                <a id="SupplyLink" href="../HTML/Supply.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Supply.png">Supply
                </a>
                <a id="BrokerLink" href="../HTML/Broker.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Broker.png">Broker
                </a>
                <a id="DiscordLink" href="https://discord.gg/pKpw3Bk">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Discord.png">Discord
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1 id="BestProfit">Best Profit</h1>
        <h2 id="BestProfitDescription">These products have the highest profit gap.</h2>
        <ul id="TopProfit" class="ProductList">
        </ul>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Request.js"></script><script>RequestProducts("TopProfit", "Profit", 6)</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Topbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Overview.css">
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your html code with the question also, so that the issue can be reproduced and checked, Thanks

Comment: You have two css files (Topbar.css and Overview.css) referenced in your html. Only giving us the snippet of the css that you did above is not helpful as it doesnt resemble what you have at all. Please post all of your css.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see any `id` Product or `class` Product in your html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62370912/13722165 is this solution of that ?...................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add css:

```css
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
}

#BestProfit {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffbc82;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 60px;
    
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#BestProfitDescription {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 100px;
    
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.ProductList {
    width: 640px;
    height: 780px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}

.Product {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    width: 300px;
    height: 240px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

#NameText {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 600;
    top: -15px;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: Montserrat,system-ui;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffbc82;
}

#ProfitText {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    font-family: Montserrat,system-ui;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="../Images/Other/Stonk.gif" id="Icon">
        <title id="Title">stonks.in | Bazzar Tracker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Request.js"></script>
        <div id="TopBar">
            <img id="Logo" src="../Images/Other/Logo.png">
            <div id="Pages">
                <a id="OverviewLink" href="../HTML/Overview.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Overview.png">Overview
                </a>
                <a id="ProfitLink" href="../HTML/Profit.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Profit.png">Profit
                </a>
                <a id="SmartLink" href="../HTML/Smart.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Smart.png">Smart
                </a>
                <a id="DemandLink" href="../HTML/Demand.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Demand.png">Demand
                </a>
                <a id="SupplyLink" href="../HTML/Supply.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Supply.png">Supply
                </a>
                <a id="BrokerLink" href="../HTML/Broker.html">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Broker.png">Broker
                </a>
                <a id="DiscordLink" href="https://discord.gg/pKpw3Bk">
                    <img id="Icon" src="../Images/Icons/Discord.png">Discord
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1 id="BestProfit">Best Profit</h1>
        <h2 id="BestProfitDescription">These products have the highest profit gap.</h2>
        <ul id="TopProfit" class="ProductList">
        </ul>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Request.js"></script><script>RequestProducts("TopProfit", "Profit", 6)</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Topbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Overview.css">
</html>
```